# <ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>

Tags: qgis, postgresql, wms, qgis-server, getcapabilities

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.12.3 and QGIS Server and I have the following issue: a WMS generated based on a set of data stored in a Postgres db returns on GetCapabilities: `<ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>`.

I also checked the QGIS Server logs and the error it is similar and it is too generic to know where to search.

Answer (score 0):

One recent mention of this error can be found in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33200:

> IF instead of
>
> ```
> FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE "pc6project.qgz"
> ```
>
> I use
>
> ```
> FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/pc6project.qgz"
> ```
>
> THEN the data is found...

This may solve your issue as well.

Comment: Not working, I tried to do this

Comment: It is like there is no connection to db

Comment: I solved the problem, the issue was connection to DB, just like I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to stock the username and the password in the Postgresql connection properties in QGIS.